# How to achieve a rolling update with docker-compose?

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I have a following setup in docker compose

- `nginx` for proxying to `frontend`, `backend` and serving static content
- `backend` app on port 8080 (spring boot)
- `frontend` app on port 4000 (node for SSR)
- `mysql` used by `backend`

Frontend can be updated relatively fast using

```
docker-compose up -d --no-deps frontend
```

Unfortunately `backend` takes about 1 minute to start.

Is there an easy way to achieve lower downtime without having to change the current setup too much? I like how simple it is right now.

I would imagine something like this:

1. Start a new instance of `backend`
2. Wait till it starts (it could be per timer or a healthtest)
3. Close the previously running instance

Comment: You might be better off with Swarm, but also could look into why it takes the backend service so long to start.

Comment: This is extremely interesting! Would you share your `docker-compose.yml` file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Here is the script I've ended up using:

```
PREVIOUS_CONTAINER=$(docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}  {{.Names}}  {{.CreatedAt}}" | grep backend | awk -F  "  " '{print $1}')
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --scale backend=2 --no-recreate backend
sleep 100
docker kill -s SIGTERM $PREVIOUS_CONTAINER
sleep 1
docker rm -f $PREVIOUS_CONTAINER
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --scale backend=1 --no-recreate backend
docker-compose stop http-nginx
docker-compose up -d --no-deps --build http-nginx
```

Comment: Why do you need to restart `http-nginx`?

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger without restarting nginx is unable to route the traffic to newly started backend. I've read about plugins to do it properly, but restarting was a lot easier for me

Comment: @MarcinKunert this should solve the dns cache problem without restarting nginx https://serverfault.com/a/916786/130859

Comment: A simpler way to get the ID of the currently running container for a service called `backend`, is to use `docker-compose ps -q backend`. Also, in case you have other Docker containers running containing that name, then it won't return their container IDs, it will just return the ID of the `backend` from your Docker Compose file :)

Comment: @Bart van Oort thanks for the tip! I'll try to incorporate it :)

Answer (score 19):

Swarm is the right solution to go, but this is still painfully doable with docker-compose.

First, ensure your proxy can do service discovery. You can't use container_name (as you can't use it in swarm) because your will increase the number of container of the same service. Proxy like traefik or nginx-proxy uses labels to do this.

Then, `docker-compose up -d --scale backend=2 --no-recreate` this creates a new container with the new image without touching the running one.

After it's up and running, `docker kill old_container`, then `docker-compose up -d --scale backend=1 --no-recreate` just to reset the number.

---

EDIT 1

`docker kill old_container` should be `docker rm -f old_container`

EDIT 2

> how to handle even and not even runs

We want to always kill the oldest containers

```
docker rm -f $(docker ps --format "table {{.ID}}  {{.Names}}  {{.CreatedAt}}" | grep backend | (read -r; printf "%s\n" "$REPLY"; sort -k 3 ) | awk -F  "  " '{print $1}' | head -1)
```

Comment: I've tried this and unfortunately it doesn't work. Scaling up works perfectly, but killing the container causes problems. The service stops responding at all instead of forwarding the traffic to the running container. It is a shame that scaling down to 1 container always stops the newer container instead of the older one.

Comment: @MarcinKunert I think the issue is on your nginx config. How do you config your reverse proxy?

Comment: server {
        listen 80;

        location /api {
            proxy_pass http://backend:8080;
        }

Comment: Seems that you are correct. I've looked a bit and: https://github.com/jwilder/nginx-proxy might be a way to go about it

Comment: docker-compose does not provide a built-in load balancer, it won't redirect traffic to the new container automatically. That't why you have to have a proxy with service discovery.

Comment: I'm now trying to restart the nginx container and it also seems to do the trick. Unfortunately during scaling back to 1 docker decides to kill the only one running container and start a new one.

Comment: weird, if that running container was created with the updated image, `docker-compose up -d --scale backend=1 --no-recreate` should not kill it.

Comment: Found the issue, I had not only to kill the previous container but also to remove it. The last (at least I hope so) issue now is to handle even and not even runs. Sometimes there will be backend_1 running at the start, but after the next deploy there will be backend_2 left. I've tried already with `docker rename` but it doesn't work and `docker-compose up` creates `backend_3` even though there is no `backend_2`

Comment: You are reading my mind! I was looking how to kill the last container.

Comment: It finally works. Instead of looking for the older container I've decided to save the id of the existing container before starting the script. I've also added a chance for the backend to exit gracefully `docker kill -s SIGTERM $PREVIOUS_CONTAINER`. Thanks for help!

Comment: Did you find a way to restart the naming of the containers? I realised that there's the label `"com.docker.compose.container-number": "2"` which is probably the one that makes the `backend_*` to keep increasing after each deploy (even if they're renamed). But I'm not sure if it's possible to edit that label, any idea?