# spring-boot-devtools Automatic Restart not working

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker, spring-boot-devtools

I have a working Spring Boot 2.25 application built with mvn. As per [this documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.1.5.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html) I add

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

From the documentation:

> As DevTools monitors classpath resources, the only way to trigger a restart is to update the classpath. The way in which you cause the classpath to be updated depends on the IDE that you are using. In Eclipse, saving a modified file causes the classpath to be updated and triggers a restart. In IntelliJ IDEA, building the project (Build -> Build Project) has the same effect.

With the application running I tried a simple

```
touch /path/to/app.jar
```

expecting the application to restart but nothing happened.

Okay, so maybe it's doing something smarter. I modified some source .java, recompiled the .jar, and `cp`'d it to replace the running .jar file and... nothing happened.

Also from the documentation

> DevTools relies on the application context’s shutdown hook to close it during a restart. It does not work correctly if you have disabled the shutdown hook (SpringApplication.setRegisterShutdownHook(false)).

I am not doing this.

> DevTools needs to customize the ResourceLoader used by the ApplicationContext. If your application provides one already, it is going to be wrapped. Direct override of the getResource method on the ApplicationContext is not supported.

I am not doing this.

I am running this in a Docker container, if that matters. From the documentation:

> Developer tools are automatically disabled when running a fully packaged application. If your application is launched from java -jar or if it is started from a special classloader, then it is considered a “production application”. If that does not apply to you (i.e. if you run your application from a container), consider excluding devtools or set the -Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=false system property.

I don't understand what this means or if it is relevant.

I want to recompile a .jar and replace it in the running docker container and trigger and application restart without restarting the container. How can I do this?

EDIT: I am using `mvn` to rebuild the jar, then `docker cp` to replace it in the running container. (IntelliJ IDEA claims to rebuild the project, but the jar files are actually *not* touched, but that's another story.) I am looking for a non-IDE-specific solution.

Comment: Is the `Build Automatically` option inside the Project menu is enabled.

Comment: i think you are asking too much from java and docker. there are so many continuous deployment tools build for this purpose. the name specifies "dev"tools which is for development environment not production. your solution is CI/CD which automates all these steps. also if you want to do it automatically you can call your git webhook from a shell scripts and after pushing your code build mvn and then build new docker image and run your image.

Answer (score 5):

The Spring Boot Devtools offers for Spring Boot applications the functionality that usually is available in IDEs like IntelliJ in which you have the ability to, for example, [restart an application](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) or force a [live browser reload](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart) when certain classes or resources change. This can be very useful in the development phase of your application.

It is typically used in conjunction with an IDE in such a way that it will be launched with the rest of your application by Spring Boot when detected in the classpath and if it is not disabled.

Although you can configure it to monitor further resources, it will usually look for changes in your application code, in your classes and resources.

It is important to say that, AFAIK, Devtools will monitor your own classes and resources in an *exploded* way, I mean, the restart process will not work if you overwrite your whole application jar, only if you overwrite some resources in your `classes` directory.

This functionality can be tested with Maven. Please, consider download a simple blueprint from [Spring Initializr](https://start.spring.io), with Spring Boot, Spring Boot Devtools and Spring Web, for example - in order to keep the application running. From a terminal, in the directory that contains the `pom.xml` file, run your application, for instance, with the help of the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` plugin included in the `pom.xml`:

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

The command will download the project dependencies, compile and run your application.

Now, perform any modification in your source code, either in your classes or in your resources and, from another terminal, in the same directory, recompile your resources:

```
mvn compile
```

If you look at the first terminal window you will see that the application is restarted to reflect the changes.

If you are using docker for your application deployment, try reproducing this behavior can be tricky.

On one hand, I do not know if it makes sense, but you can try creating a maven based image and run your code inside, just as described above. Your `Dockerfile` can look similar to this:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as maven

WORKDIR /app

# Copy project pom
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml

# Fetch (and cache) dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy source files
COPY ./src ./src

# Run your application
RUN mvn springboot:run
```

With this setup, you can copy with `docker cp` your resources to the `/app/target` directory and it will trigger an application restart. As an alternative, consider mounting a volume in your container instead of using `docker cp`.

**Much better**, and taking into account the fact that overwriting your application jar will probably not work, you can try to copy both your classes and library dependencies, and run your application in a exploded way. Consider the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as maven

WORKDIR /app

# Copy your project pom
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml

# Fetch (and cache) dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy source files
COPY ./src ./src

# Compile application and library dependencies
# The dependencies will, by default, be copied to target/dependency
RUN mvn clean compile dependency:copy-dependencies -Dspring-boot.repackage.skip=true

# Final run image (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691781/how-to-cache-maven-dependencies-in-docker)
FROM openjdk:8u171-jre-alpine
# OPTIONAL: copy dependencies so the thin jar won't need to re-download them
# COPY --from=maven /root/.m2 /root/.m2

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy classes from maven image
COPY --from=maven /app/target/classes ./classes

# Copy dependent libraries
COPY --from=maven /app/target/dependency ./lib

EXPOSE 8080

# Please, modify your main class name as appropriate
ENTRYPOINT ["java", "-cp", "/app/classes:/app/lib/*", "com.example.demo.DemoApplication"]
```

The important line in the `Dockerfile` is this:

```
mvn clean compile dependency:copy-dependencies -Dspring-boot.repackage.skip=true
```

It will instruct maven to compile your resources and copy the required libraries. Although redundant for the typical Maven phase in which the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` `repackage` goal runs, the flag `spring-boot.repackage.skip=true` will instruct this plugin to not repackage the application.

With this `Dockerfile`, build you image (let's tag it `devtools-demo`, for example):

```
docker build -t devtools-demo .
```

And run it:

```
docker run devtools-demo:latest
```

With this setup, if now you change your classes and/or resources, and run `mvn` locally:

```
mvn compile
```

you should be able to force the restart mechanism in your container with the following `docker cp` command:

```
docker cp classes <container name>:/app/classes
```

Please, again, consider mounting a volume in your container instead of using `docker cp`.

I tested the setup and it worked properly.

The important think to keep in mind is to replace your exploded resources, not the whole application jar.

As another option, you can take an approach similar to the one indicated in your comments and run your Devtools in remote mode:

```
FROM maven:3.5-jdk-8 as maven

WORKDIR /app

# Copy project pom
COPY ./pom.xml ./pom.xml

# Fetch (and cache) dependencies
RUN mvn dependency:go-offline -B

# Copy source files
COPY ./src ./src

# Build jar
RUN mvn package && cp target/your-app-version.jar app.jar

# Final run image (based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53691781/how-to-cache-maven-dependencies-in-docker)
FROM openjdk:8u171-jre-alpine
# OPTIONAL: copy dependencies so the thin jar won't need to re-download them
# COPY --from=maven /root/.m2 /root/.m2

# Change working directory
WORKDIR /app

# Copy artifact from the maven image
COPY --from=maven /app/app.jar ./app.jar

ENV JAVA_DOCKER_OPTS "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:8000,suspend=n"

ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=true"

EXPOSE 8000

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "exec java $JAVA_DOCKER_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar /app/app.jar"]
```

For the Spring Boot Devtools remote mode to work properly, you need several things (some of them pointed out by Opri as well in his/her answer).

First, you need to configure the `spring-boot-maven-plugin` to [include the devtools](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-remote) in your application jar (it will be excluded otherwise, by default):

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <configuration>
    <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
  </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Then, you need to setup a value for the configuration property `spring.devtools.remote.secret`. This property has to do with the way remote debugging works in Spring Boot Devtools.

The remote debugging functionality consists of two parts, a client and a server. Basically, the client is a copy of your server code, and it uses the value of the `spring.devtools.remote.secret` configuration property to authenticate itself against the server.

This client code should be [run from an IDE](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#_running_the_remote_client_application), and you attach your IDE debugging process to a local server exposed from that client.

Every change performed in the client monitored resources, remember, the same as in your server, is pushed to the remote server and it will trigger a restart if necessary.

As you can see, this functionality is again more appropriate from a development point of view.

If you need to actually restart your application by overwriting your jar application file, maybe a better approach will be to configure your docker container to run a shell script in your `ENTRYPOINT` or `CMD`. This shell script will monitor a copy of your jar, in a certain directory. If that resource changes, as a consequence of your `docker cp`, this shell script will stop the current running application version - this application is supposed to run from a different location to avoid problems when updating the jar -, replace the current jar with the new one, and then start the new application version. Not the same, but please, consider read [this related SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4002462/how-can-i-write-a-java-application-that-can-update-itself-at-runtime).

In any case, when you run an application in a container, you are trying to provide a consistent and platform independent way of deployment for it. From this perspective, instead of monitoring changes in your docker container, a more convenient approach may be to generate and to deploy a new version of your container image with those new changes. This process can be automated greatly using tools like Jenkins, Travis, etcetera. These tools allow you to define CI/CD pipelines that, in response to a code commit, for example, can generate on the fly a docker image with your code and, it configured accordingly, deploy later this image to services like some docker flavor or Kubernetes, on premises or in the cloud. Some of them, especially Kubernetes, but [swarm](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/swarm-tutorial/rolling-update/) an even [docker compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49090395/how-to-achieve-a-rolling-update-with-docker-compose) as well, will allow you to perform rolling updates without or with minimal application service interruption.

To conclude, probably it will not fit your needs, but be aware that you can use [`spring-boot-starter-actuator`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#production-ready) directly or with [Spring Boot Admin](https://github.com/codecentric/spring-boot-admin), for instance, to restart your application.

Finally, as already indicated in the Spring Boot Devtools documentation, you can try a different option, not based on restart but in application reload, in hot swapping. This functionality is offered by commercial products like [JRebel](https://www.jrebel.com/products/jrebel) although there are some open sources alternatives as well, mainly [dcevm](https://dcevm.github.io) and the [HotswapAgent](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/HotswapAgent). [This related article](https://dzone.com/articles/hot-swap-java-bytecode-on-runtime) provides some insight in how these last two products work. [This Github project](https://github.com/HotswapProjects/hotswap-docklands) provides complementary information about how to run it in docker containers.

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar problem when using intellij idea, I saw somewhere that you had to use the build button for it to work.

[image]

In jsp the application reloads the files, it is not completely automatic, because intellij saves automatically -> this behavior is the default but there is I think a way to change it. -> To record manually and then that it reloads automatically.

Works for jsp apps only, if you try this with standard apps it will create a double frame execution (swing)

Comment: automatic build, see this article: https://medium.com/@bhanuchaddha/spring-boot-devtools-on-intellij-c0ab3f9afa63 (i don't know if it works)

Comment: I am building with `mvn`, prefer non-IDE solution. Also I have [this other problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67279275/intellij-claims-to-build-but-jar-files-are-not-touched)

Answer (score 2):

**If you are using IntelliJ try below option**

1. Make sure you have updated pom.xml with dev dependency

   ```
   <dependency>
       <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
   </dependency>
   ```
2. Go to Settings in Intellij click on Build,Execution, Deployment
3. Click on Compiler
4. Now click on Build Project Automatically
   [image]

5)After this click on Advanced Settings and enable auto-make start

[image]

6. Lastly stop the server and restart it, you will see the change

Answer (score 1):

I am no shore because you are not saying explicitly if you tried this things but:

- try to set this on true:`(SpringApplication.setRegisterShutdownHook(true))`
- try adding manually in the dockerfile this property   `-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=true`

> I know it says that on default should be on true, but try to do it
> manually

Maybe show us the dockerfile.

Later Edit:
Saw this in documentation:

> repackaged archives do not contain devtools by default. If you want to
> use certain remote devtools feature, you’ll need to disable the
> excludeDevtools build property to include it. The property is
> supported with both the Maven and Gradle plugins.

The Spring Boot developer tools are not just limited to local development. You can also use several features when running applications remotely. Remote support is opt-in, to enable it you need to make sure that **devtools** is included in the repackaged archive:

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <excludeDevtools>false</excludeDevtools>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Then you need to set a **spring.devtools.remote.secret** property, for example:

```
spring.devtools.remote.secret=mysecret
```

***Remote devtools support is provided in two parts; there is a server side endpoint that accepts connections, and a client application that you run in your IDE. The server component is automatically enabled when the spring.devtools.remote.secret property is set. The client component must be launched manually.***

[Documents from spring](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-remote)

Comment: I am omitting some unrelated proprietary stuff and boilerplate but the dockerfile is basically

`ENV JAVA_DOCKER_OPTS "-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=y,address=*:8000,suspend=n"`

`ENV JAVA_OPTS "-Dspring.devtools.restart.enabled=true"`

`WORKDIR $APPLICATION_DIR`

`ENTRYPOINT ["/bin/bash", "-lc", "exec java $JAVA_DOCKER_OPTS $JAVA_OPTS -jar $APPLICATION_DIR/$APPLICATION_NAME.jar"]`

Answer (score 0):

In order to restart app with devtools you need to make sure following things.

1. Use any IDE or Build tools like maven gradle to start app
2. Using java -jar devtools will not work as it packages app.
3. Using maven you can run app like mvn spring-boot:run

[Refer official documentation for more details.](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.5.16.RELEASE/reference/html/using-boot-devtools.html#using-boot-devtools-restart)

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issue after using dependency also spring boot was not picking up devtools configuration so I did following steps in eclipse.

1. installed eclipse (assuming you have already installed)
2. installed sts plugin from eclipse market (since i am eclipse generic version lover so prefer generic eclipse on top of that i installed sts plugin)
3. project --> build automatically
4. debug as --> spring boot application
5. done.